# Why use a tuple rather than an array or dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I don't understand what the benefit of using a tuple could be over an array. So far it seems that the only difference between the two types is that a tuple is one type containing multiple values. But that's exactly what arrays are!?

Comment: Related: [Why to use tuples when we can use array to return multiple values in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773189/why-to-use-tuples-when-we-can-use-array-to-return-multiple-values-in-swift)

Comment: Tuple = quick-struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tuple can contain elements of different types. So for example you could declare a tuple containing a String and an Int, while all elements of an array have to be the same type, unless you use AnyObject and type casting.

Answer (score 9):

For me the benefit of tuples are:

- easy access (no subscripting)
- no type casting
- ability to name the
  members (e.g. let http200Status = (statusCode: 200, description:
  "OK")
- convenience way to return multiple values from a function

From the Swift Language Guide:

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not
>   suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data
>   structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a
>   class or structure, rather than as a tuple

Answer (score 0):

In a tuple you can store elements of different types like `Double` and `String`. In addition to this you can also specify element names and access them by name:

```
let respond = (myString: "Hey it's", answer: 42 )
respond.myString // "Hey it's"
respond.answer   // 42
```

So it's like a struct which you can make without a declaration.