# what's difference between array and tuple

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I've started to learn what does tuple mean and I faced with the question what's difference between Array and Tuples. So, I'm just schoolboy who want to learn Swift and I still don't know a lot of things

Comment: [Swift Fundamentals Tuples](https://cocoacasts.com/swift-fundamentals-tuples) read this blog.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773189/why-to-use-tuples-when-we-can-use-array-to-return-multiple-values-in-swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101869/why-use-a-tuple-rather-than-an-array-or-dictionary-in-swift

Answer (score 14):

**Tuple**
A tuple is a grouping of unnamed, ordered values. Each value in a tuple does not need to be the same type.

**Array**
An array is mutable collection. They are very efficient to create, but must always be a single type.

Comment: an array is not necessarily of a fixed size. its size may change

Answer (score -3):

**Arrays** - Arrays are ordered collections of values. For example :

```
let someArray: [String] = ["Alex", "Brian", "Dave"]
```

Please read this : [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.1) - Collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) 
,this : [Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array).

**Tuples** - A tuple type is a comma-separated list of types, enclosed in parentheses. For example :

```
var someTuple = (top: 10, bottom: 12)  // someTuple is of type (top: Int, bottom: Int)
```

Please read this : [Apple Developer Documentation - Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)